# Does this home network configuration make sense?

Tags: networking, nas

I'm investing in a new Synology NAS and am taking the opportunity to improve my home network. The image depicts my proposed configuration. The network switch, NAS and ethernet cables would be new purchases and could be swapped with alternatives if these are not the right choices. The Google Wifi is already in place and I'd like to keep it.

[image: my proposed configuration]

Questions:

1. Is the proposed switch adequate (aka fast enough) to sit between the router and the NAS?
2. For reasons of price and convenience I plan to by the NAS and switch in the United States and they will come with 120V power adapters.  But I will use the gear in Hong Kong where the plugs are 220V UK style.  Would it be OK to use inexpensive plug adapters to convert the plug types, such as a [3-Prong USA to 3-Prong UK (Type G)](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/666360-REG/Watson_APG_USA_GB_Adapter_Plug_USA_to.html)?
3. What type of ethernet cabling should I use between all of these components? I'm thoroughly confused by the variety of cable types on the market.

Comment: It makes sense, however you're going to want to configure vLANs to firewall the NAS, Mac/other PCs/servers from the Apple TV, SmartTV, and other media devices.  Mobile devices and IoT devices also need their own vLANs _(this firewalls your LAN from an exploited device on it - mobile and IoT devices must always be on their own vLAN)_.  As to ethernet cables, unless you have >=10G+ / fiber-optic network cards, gigabit CAT6a cables from [MonoPrice](https://www.monoprice.com/category/cables/networking-patch-cables/cat6a-ethernet-cables) would be sufficient (they lifetime warranty all their cables)

Comment: While off-topic to what you're asking, if you haven't already done so, you'll likely want to also invest in a UPS when you buy your NAS, else you risk data loss/corruption upon a power outage; The NAS can then be configured to cleanly shut down immediately upon the UPS losing power or be configured to do so if the power hasn't been restored within an arbitrary amount of time (say 30s).  For computers and servers, a pure sine wave UPS is preferable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question 2

I suggest the type of products [here](https://www.leadsdirect.co.uk/product-category/mains-leads-and-accessories/uk-type-g-mains-leads/uk-type-g-to-iec-c13/), instead of the adapter for the Synology NAS (see the datasheet linked below for rated voltage and frequency).

Essentially, get a cable that plugs into the wall where you are, and has an NEC C13 plug on the other end.  Make sure your mains (outlet) voltage is between 100V and 240V (most places in the US and UK in residences?) and either 50Hz (UK / Europe?) or 60Hz (US).

Question 1

The Synology NAS comes with 4 ports capable of link aggregation (4Gbps) built-in.  The switch is not capable of that (unmanaged means you can't configure link aggregation on that side).  The NAS also comes with a PCIe 3.0 slot that can handle a 10Gbps network card.  The switch cannot interface with that.  This is per information [here](https://global.download.synology.com/download/Document/Hardware/DataSheet/DiskStation/18-year/DS1618+/enu/Synology_DS1618_Plus_Data_Sheet_enu.pdf) (Synology) and [here](http://www.downloads.netgear.com/files/GDC/datasheet/en/UnmanagedSwitches200.pdf) (switch).

Question 3

It is gigabit ethernet.  You're fine with category 5e and up.  If you are going for longer network runs (don't worry about across the desk or room), get higher rated cable (Cat6, Cat7).

My question for you is: How is the router interacting with your NAS that you are concerned for performance?  Typically I would expect you would interact between the computer(s), maybe the smart TV and the NAS.

Comment: Good question.  I plan to back up from the NAS to AWS Glacier.  The first sync will take a long time but I'm not very concerned because that will run in the background.  Otherwise performance between the NAS and router is not that important.  That part of my question comes from a desire for symmetry from the standpoint of matching the speeds.  I figure if I'm investing in new networking equipment I might as well aim for consistency.

Comment: Unless you have a connection to your ISP that is 1Gbps or better (rare, but not unheard of), the link between the NAS and the router won't be the limiting factor for sending data to AWS Glacier.  If your Internet connection is 1Gbps or better, then it may be that you could benefit from a router and switch upgrade.

Answer (score 1):

1. Your switch is fast enough - its just switching packets, not routing them.
2. You need to make sure the power supplies are switched and can handle the voltage - but it should work. I would buy a multiboard to plug everything into and a single decent adaptor rather then multiple adaptors.  Again, be mindful of the voltage risk.
3. You need cable that supports gigabit speeds. Cat6 is probably ideal, but cat5e can work.  Rather buy premade leads then crimp your own.